# why does tkinter Entry widget returns empty sting while using multiple windows but seems to work in a single window?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am building  a project in python using tkinter but when using multiple windows in tkinter, I have encountered a problem, In my Code Which you can see below, In my first window ,by pressing Open Entry Box button, I can open my second window from there i want to take value using *Entry box* to be store in local database but whenever I try to do so each time it returns an empty string. but it works in a single window though From This code I have given a Brief idea  what i want to achieve

```
from tkinter import *
import pymysql
class Sample():
    def __init__(self,root):
        self.root = root
        self.root.geometry("200x200")
        S_Button = Button(root,text="Open entry Box",command=self.add).pack()
        

    def add(self):
        self.second = Tk()
        self.second.geometry("500x200")

        self.SRN = StringVar()
        S_entry = Entry(self.second,textvariable=self.SRN).pack()

        S_Button2 = Button(self.second,text="Store in Database",command=self.data).pack()

        self.second.mainloop()


    def data(self):
        print(self.SRN.get())
        #con = pymysql.connect(host="localhost",user="root",password="",database="stm")
        # cur = con.cursor()
        # cur.execute("insert into StudentsData value (%s),(self.SRN.get()))
        # con.commit()
        # con.close()'''
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is you are using two instances of `Tk()`. Doing so means you have two seperate instances of `Tk()` running that essentially can't interact with each other (a great explanation of this can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48045508/12664040)). Hence why you aren't able to store the text from the `Entry` box in `StringVar` and it only returns an empty string. Instead, use `Toplevel()`. It does what you are wanting to do while only using one `Tk()`. Working example using `Toplevel`:

```
import tkinter as tk

class Sample():
    def __init__(self,root):
        self.root = root
        self.root.geometry("200x200")
        S_Button = tk.Button(root,text="Open entry Box",command=self.add)
        S_Button.pack()
        

    def add(self):
        self.second = tk.Toplevel(self.root)
        self.second.geometry("500x200")

        # Widgets, StringVar
        self.SRN = tk.StringVar()
        S_entry = tk.Entry(self.second,textvariable=self.SRN)
        S_Button2 = tk.Button(self.second,text="Store in Database",command=self.data)

        # Packing widgets
        S_entry.pack()
        S_Button2.pack()



    def data(self):
        self.second.destroy()
        print(self.SRN.get())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = Sample(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

Don't use `from tkinter import *`, it doesn't follow [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/). Instead use `import tkinter as tk` or similar. Don't use `button = tk.Button().pack()`. Seperate the button creation from the packing, this makes it much easier to order your widgets properly when there are more of them.

Comment: great follow up thanks :)